# Replacing => in place of -> in function type signature

Tags: haskell

I just observed that if instead of `->`, I write `=>` in the type signature definition of a function, it doesn't result in an compile time error. Example code:

```
mysum :: Num a => [a] => a -- Notice => after the list [a]
mysum [] = 0
mysum (x:xs) = x + mysum xs
```

Why does this happen ? And is there a way to avoid this ?

Compiler Used: GHC 7.6.2

**Update**: Successful compilation in [ideone](http://ideone.com/YY1Yzy).

Comment: Perhaps it's an error correcting compiler. If you have read the Purple Dragon Book then you would know that some compilers can catch common mistakes and automatically correct them. Whether that is good behaviour is open to debate.

Comment: I have GHC 7.8.2, and at least there it's an error.

Comment: This gives me an error both with GHC 7.8.2 and on [tryhaskell](http://tryhaskell.org/).

Comment: Then it seems to be an issue with 7.6.2. It successfully compiles in [ideone](http://ideone.com/YY1Yzy).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a bug in GHC 7.6.2.  You should try it in the most recent compiler and if it still doesn't give an error there, then you should file a bug report.

Actually, I think this bug is already [known and fixed in GHC 7.8](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/7778).

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be fixed in 7.8.2

```
foo.hs:1:19:
    Expected a constraint, but ‘[a]’ has kind ‘*’
    In the type signature for ‘mysum’: mysum :: Num a => [a] => a
```

I would assume it's just a bug specific to 7.6.x.

Comment: It seems 7.4.x, 7.8.x and 7.6.1 do not exhibit this bug.  Just 7.6.2 and 7.6.3.