# Why did my mistake annotating this type signature not break things?

Tags: haskell, syntax, types

I had defined an alias for the function `execState`:

```
myCleverName = execState
```

GHC warned about a top-level binding with no annotated type signature, so I'd written:

```
myCleverName :: State s a => s -> s
```

Immediately obvious to most of you is that "fat arrow" `=>` should have just been a regular skinny one `->`. But I only just noticed that today, yet both the module containing the alias and the code using the alias have been compiling fine for weeks, with not so much as a warning that I used the wrong syntax. Why is that?

Thanks!

Comment: I just tried it myself and got the following error- " Expected a constraint, but ‘State s a’ has kind ‘*’ In the type signature for ‘myCleverName’: myCleverName :: State s a => s -> s".  Are you sure the bad code was compiling?  Can you remove other stuff from the program until you have the minimal lines and still no error?

Comment: Something related to that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23989573/replacing-in-place-of-in-function-type-signature

Answer (score 8, accepted):

GHC 7.6.3 had a bug that allowed things like this but it's fixed (or should be) in GHC 7.8. Internally, type class constraints are represented as implicit function arguments and I think that's why 7.6.3 was confused. They still are represented that way, but the sanity checking has been improved.

Comment: Gotcha :) Indeed, 7.6.3 is what I have